# "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres" when compiled with pyinstaller in windowed mode

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have a module that is writen in python3. When I install it with pip I can start my GUI.
Now I tried to create a compiled executable with pyinstaller(3.6) on WIndows 10.

My script file (run.py) that i compile looks like this:

```py
import chatwolf

root = chatwolf.GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

My Powershell command for compiling looks like this:

```
pyinstaller --add-data="README.md;." --add-data="LICENSE.txt;." 
--add-data="doc/pdf/chatwolf.pdf;doc" --add-data="chatwolf/data/messages;data/messages" 
--add-data="chatwolf/data/conf_root.json;data/" --add-data="chatwolf/data/icon.png;data/" 
--name="Chatwolf" --icon=install/icon.ico --onefile --clean --windowed --noconfirm run.py
```

If I do the compilation without the argumen --windowed I can start my executable from the console
But if I add this option I always get the error mesage "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres"

Has anyone an idea how to overcome this error?

From searching I got already, that this is do to the pkg_resource model.

I tried:
- changing my module code, so I don't use the pkg_resource module in my chatwolf module. 
- added --hidden-import="pkg_resource.py2_warn"
- updated pyinstaller and pkg_resource

Nothing helped!

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the `--hidden-import="pkg_resource.py2_warn"` command does solve this problem.
I just had a spelling mistake.